# Find matrix with respect to basis

Tags: linear-transformations

I need help with this problem, the problem is that I don't know where to start.

- $T(a) = -5a + (-2)b + 2c $
- $T(a+b) = a + 7b + c$
- $T(a+c) = -13a + (-9)b + 18c$

I know that the first one is just $(-5,-2,2)$ but I don't know what to do when it's written like the other two. Should I try to "remove" $b$ from $T(2a + b)$ in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $T(a)=-2a-2b+7c$. You also know the\begin{align}T(b)&=T(b+2a-2a)\\&=T(b+2a)-T(2a)\\&=8a + 4b + c-2T(a)\\&=8a + 4b + c-2(-2a-2b+7c)\\&=12a+8b-13c\end{align}and that\begin{align}T(c)&=T(c-b+b)\\&=T(c-b)+T(b)\\&=-12a-8b+17c+12a+8b-13c\\&=4c.\end{align}So, the matrix that you're after is$$\begin{bmatrix}-2&12&0\\-2&8&0\\7&-13&4\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thank you! I Accidentally wrote (-a + c) instead of (-b+c) for T(c), I tried to solve it myself and got (0,0,4), is that correct?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Why is T(a) = -2a-2b+7c? Clearly it's T(a) = -5a+(-2)b+2c

Comment: @DavidKwak The question was [edited](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3969028/revisions) *after* my answer was posted.